# Get data for every Friday between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL-Server database in which I want to get the data from the column VL_DR between two given dates and where the date is a Friday.

```
"SELECT VL_DR FROM table_VL WHERE date>='" + date_start
                + "' AND date<='" + date_end
                + "' AND DATENAME(dw, date)='Friday'"
```

But after the request I have an empty list while I should have some values.
What should I fix to get the correct request?

Comment: What does Table_VL look like, structure and sample data

Comment: The table_VL have a column VL_DR, a column date and others column not usefull here. In the VL_DR there is number and datetime in the date column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its SQL Server

Try

`SELECT VL_DR FROM table_VL WHERE ([date] BETWEEN date_start and date_end) AND LOWER(DATENAME(dw, [date]))='friday'`

If its MySQL

Try

`SELECT VL_DR FROM table_VL WHERE ([date] BETWEEN date_start and date_end) AND DAYNAME([date])='Friday'`

Comment: Its in SQL server (I have edited my post), but with your request its still an empty list when it shouldn't. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Lukasc Change `DATENAME(dw, [date])='Friday'` to `LOWER(DATENAME(dw, [date]))='friday'`  It could be that your server is case sensitive if you are sure there is data on a Friday in that date range.

Comment: I have checked there is data on friday in the date range, but its still not working with the lower function.

Comment: @Lukasc If you run this do you see the data as you would expect? `SELECT VL_DR, [date], LOWER(DATENAME(dw, [date])) FROM table_VL`

Comment: When I run the last request i saw that the day are not in english, so with friday in the proper language it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lukasc no problem, glad I could help get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL. `DAYNAME` should work

```
"SELECT VL_DR FROM table_VL WHERE date>='" + date_start
            + "' AND date<='" + date_end
            + "' AND DAYNAME(date)='Friday'"
```

Example:

```
SELECT DAYNAME('2008-05-15');
```

results `Thursday`

Answer (score 0):

This code will work, based on data in a Share Code database that I have.  This is for MS-SQL.

```
SELECT
    CloseDate, DatePart(WEEKDAY,CloseDate) AS DAY_OF_WEEK_No , SharePrice 
FROM
    SharePrice 
WHERE
    CloseDate BETWEEN '01 October 2014' AND '31 October 2014'
AND
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY,CloseDate) = 6 -- 1=Sunday; 7=Saturday
AND
    ShareCode = 'AGL'
```