# Find all fridays with date in the year 2017

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a MySQL query that will fetch all Fridays with date for the year 2017.

I know that SQL query for the same is:

```
SELECT Fridays = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)
FROM (SELECT TOP 366 num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.NAME)-1 FROM dbo.syscolumns a, dbo.syscolumns b) n
WHERE DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), n.num)) = 'Friday'
```

I am looking for a MySQL alternative for the same.

Comment: Do you already have a table containing all dates in 2017?  By the way, the code you posted is SQL Server code, not MySQL.

Comment: yes i Know its sql, I'm looking for something similar in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This is an exact conversion of your sql logic in mysql

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year(now()),1), INTERVAL @num:=@num+1 DAY)
From (select @num:=-1) num
where DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year(now()),1), INTERVAL @num:=@num+1 DAY))="Friday"
limit 365
```

Comment: returns me an empty resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not have row_number function until version 8. Prior to version 8 row_number can be simulated using variables.

```
select s.num , date_add(str_to_date(concat('2016','/','12','/','31'),'%Y/%m/%d'), interval s.num day) dt,
            dayname(date_add(str_to_date(concat('2016','/','12','/','31'),'%Y/%m/%d'), interval s.num day)) dy
from
(
select @num:=@num + 1 num from information_schema.columns,(select @num:=0) n
limit 35
) s
where dayname(date_add(str_to_date(concat('2016','/','12','/','31'),'%Y/%m/%d'), interval s.num day)) = 'Friday';
```

information_schema.columns is similar to dbo.syscolumns.

```
------+------------+--------+
| num  | dt         | dy     |
+------+------------+--------+
|    6 | 2017-01-06 | Friday |
|   13 | 2017-01-13 | Friday |
|   20 | 2017-01-20 | Friday |
|   27 | 2017-01-27 | Friday |
|   34 | 2017-02-03 | Friday |
+------+------------+--------+
5 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.26 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ([date] BETWEEN date_start and date_end) AND 
DAYNAME([date])='Friday'
```

Source of the query: [Get data for every friday between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659516/get-data-for-every-friday-between-two-dates)